# filter lines in csv and save to a new csv file

Tags: text-processing, csv

I want to filter the csv file line by line and select the lines that satisfy the if condition.

Since the csv file is separated by a comma, so the code should be something like this:

```
'BEGIN {FS=','}
{while read line 
if (condition) 
   save selected line to a new csv file
} done < file.csv'
```

How can I save the selected lines to a new csv file if it satisfies the if condition? Can anyone provide some examples?

Comment: 1) post a testable input fragment; 2) specify the crucial condition

Comment: Start with the awk tag info page on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Comment: 4/22/2018,1:00:39, 37.7875

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Python for something like this. Here is an example:

```
import csv

#Create a csv file with some data
myData = [["first_name", "second_name", "Grade"],
          ['Alex', 'Brian', 'A'],
          ['Tom', 'Smith', 'B']]

myFile1 = open('file1.csv', 'w')
with myFile1:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile1)
    writer.writerows(myData)

#Create a second csv file
myFile2 = open('file2.csv', 'w')

#Read the first file created with data
with open('file1.csv') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File)
    for row in reader:
        #Print every row to the console
        print(row)
        if row[0] == "Alex":
           #If the first cell of the row says Alex, say hi and add the row to the second file
           print "Hi Alex"
           with myFile2:
             writer = csv.writer(myFile2)
             writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` in this way

```
awk -F, '(condition) { print >"to_new.csv"}' file.csv
```

The `-F,` specify delimiter comma `,` which the fields are separated. If *condition* matched with your criteria then it will redirect the line to a new file named `to_new.csv`.

We used [single-‘`>`’ redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) here. When this type of redirection is used, the *to_new.csv* is erased before the first output is written to it. Subsequent writes to the same *to_new.csv* do not erase the file, but append to it. (This is different from how you use redirections in shell scripts.) If *to_new.csv* does not exist, it is created.

Or simply write:

```
awk -F, 'condition' file.csv > to_new.csv
```